# Plotting vectors of different lengths in R (RGL-package) for export as interactive WebGL graphic

Tags: r, data-visualization, matlab-figure, rgl

I am trying to create 3D interactive graphics for a website. The graphics show spectroscopic data of 36 different measurements. I am able to create the desired plot in matlab (https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9piq1an99rc2gc/Screenshot.jpg?dl=0). However, Matlab is unable to export the Waterfall plot in a 3D interactive format. Thus I chose R and the RGL package.
I think I am missing something that is facepalm-obvious to profilic R-users, but not to me, a R-noob. Any help would be greatly aprreciated.

I have uploaded the data (https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxd7pu7ct46afiu/Data.zip?dl=0) into RStudio and tried plotting it. X = Wavelength, Y = number of analysis, Z = intensity. I also tried to repeat "x, y) since they are always the same and only z changes.

rgl.lines(x, y, z)
rep(x, y)
lapply(z, as.numeric)

There was an error message saying that the objects cannot be coersed into type double. So I tried the lapply, apply commands and exported them as csv-files, re-imported them, but when plotting the error message still persisted. 
I think I am missing something that is facepalm-obvious to profilic R-users, but not to me, a R-noob

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible:  we don't know how you loaded `x`, `y` and `z` from those files.  Likely that's where your error occurred.

Comment: I chose the "import dataset" option from the menu bar and uploaded each file individually. Then I defined each set as x, y and z and entered the function rgl.points(x, y, z)